# open new activity with button

Tags: android

here is the code of my xml.

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Make New Account"
            android:onClick="new"
            android:textColor="#E74C3C"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"/>
```

and here is my code of java.

```
 public Button btn2;
public void onClick(){
    btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,submit.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

my button is not working yet, even an message will appear after clicking on button that unfortunately application has stopped... what is the reason??

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:-

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Make New Account"
    android:textColor="#E74C3C"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"/>
```

Put this in your activity:-

```
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,submit.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Akshay Katariya thanks but I,m not asking about toast. my problem is by pressing button new activity doesn't open.

Comment: You were supposed to replace your intent with toast message, try now i have edited my code give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfect Nida..
Just Add Your activity name in menifest file like below code,

```
 <activity android:name=".submit"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways:

**Either**

1) Set an onClick listener on the button

**Or**

2) Set an onClick attribute on the button and create a method

**Method 1**

Xml file

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Make New Account"
        android:textColor="#E74C3C"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"/>
```

Java File

```
public Button btn2;
btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,submit.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

**Method 2**

Xml file

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onclick="newAccount"
    android:text="Make New Account"
    android:textColor="#E74C3C"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"/>
```

Java file

```
public Button btn2;
btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
public void newAccount(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,submit.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you are calling the onClick function when you have declared the onClick of button as new

Try this :

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Make New Account"
        android:onClick="submit"
        android:textColor="#E74C3C"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"/>
```

And then in your activity class declare this function:

```
public void submit(View view){
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,submit.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

That's it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`Activity` is the most basic Android components is also the most common use of the four components (`Activity`, `Service`, `Content Provider`, `BroadcastReceiver`).

The steps to create an `Activity`:

1. Create a new Java class And extends the `Activity`
2. Add in the `AndroidManifest`

   ```
   <activity android:name=".ActivityClassName"/>
   ```

   If is to start the interface

   ```
   <activity android:name=".ActivityClassName">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```
3. Override the `onCreate()` function and load layout

**Note:** The Activity of the Java classes generally ends in `Activity`